# How to factor exponents?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

Given

```
Exp[a+b]
```

I want to turn it into

```
Exp[a] Exp[b]
```

How can I achieve this in general? That is I am looking for more or less universal and scalable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just came up with one solution using rules:

```
expRule = Exp[x_ + y_] -> HoldForm[E^x E^y];
```

Then

```
Exp[a] + Log[Exp[1/a + Sin[c] Sqrt[b]]] /. expRule
```

produces as desired

$$\log \left(e^{1/a} e^{\sqrt{b} \sin (c)}\right)+e^a$$